# Computation of n-step transition matrix : method of matching coefficients

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

[image]

For the third step I don't understand how they have worked out $C_1^1=0$? where did they get the value of 0  from?

p11(n)=(c01+c11n)lamda 1^n. Using p11(1)=1-a and c01=1, n=1,lamda 1=1 and lamba 1^1 =1 and so in the p11(n) equation I get c11 to be -a and not 0.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. Here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: You get the 0 and 1 in the last part by taking $n=0,1$, computing what you should have, and solving the system for the coefficients. As before you should have $p_{11}(0)=1,p_{11}(1)=1-\alpha$, so $C^0_1=1$ and $(C^0_1+C^1_1)(1-\alpha)=1-\alpha$.

Comment: p11(n)=(c01+c11n)lamda n^1. Using  p11(1)=1-a and c01=1, n=1,lamda 1=1 and lamba 1^1 =1 and so in the p11(n) equation I get  c11 to be -a and not 0.

Comment: so basically where did you get (1-a) from in (C01+C11)(1-a) when in the given p11(n) equation we have (C01+C11)(lamda 1^n) and n=1 in this case and lamda 1=1 so 1^1=1

Comment: Oh, you're right, in that case $\lambda$ is repeated. But also in that case $p_{11}(n)=1$ for all $n$ because $\beta=0$. So now the equations boil down to $C^0_1=1,C^0_1+C^1_1=1$ which gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

The $p_{11}(0)=1$ comes from definition $$p_{11}(0) = \Pr\left(X_0 = 1 \mid X_0 =1\right) = 1$$ and so does the second equation $$p_{11}(1) = \Pr\left(X_1 = 1 \mid X_0 =1\right) = \mathbb{P}_{11} = 1-\alpha$$

You can get the third step by setting $\beta = -\alpha+\epsilon$ and considering the limit $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: so would p11(2)=Pr(X2=1 given X0=1)=P11=1-a as well?

Comment: No, it would 11 component of the P^2